# Remove query strings from static resources on Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, caching

I'm having difficulties with removing query strings from static resource on my Wordpress site. I've tried the common function.php code that seems to work for most but my Pingdom analysis isn't changing.

I have WordFence and Cache Enabler installed if that affects things.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
function _remove_script_version( $src ){
    $parts = explode( '?ver', $src );
        return $parts[0];
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 ); 
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 ); 

remove_action( 'wp_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script', 7 ); 
remove_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );
```

I also have this in my .htaccess to help with caching:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On 

# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

# favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year”

# images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"

# css
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week”

# javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|svg|js|ico)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch ".(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rdf+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-woff
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
</IfModule>
```

Comment: How does the source look when you are reviewing it? I'll bet that the file is being cached. Change something else on the page to make sure even you are seeing the latest version.

Comment: Typing in the URLs of the list of sites with query strings still brings up a valid link. I've disabled the caching on wordfence for sites that have ?ver= in the URL and I've refreshed the cache afterwards. But no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP works fine. I just ran it on a staging server and it strips the versions and the emoji scripts perfectly.

With that out of the way, it is almost certainly a cache issue.

Your .htaccess shouldn't have anything to do with it since the issue is with the request being made by WordPress, not the static asset itself needing to be updated.

I would head into the settings page for Cache Enabler and hit the "Save" button. According to their documentation, that should clear all current caching and clear up your problem.

https://www.keycdn.com/support/wordpress-cache-enabler-plugin/

- Cheers!

Comment: thank you very much that worked! I should have known that it was that plugin! One question: how did you run it on a staging server?

Comment: I have a Digital Ocean droplet I use to stage client sites before taking them live. All I did was take a dev site and see if your code worked and if Pingdom picked up the change. If you're interested in setting up a staging server to play with, check out: https://serverpilot.io/community/articles/how-to-install-wordpress-on-digitalocean.html